# Помогите решить проблему с установкой cookies

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

У меня в панели стоит уведомление с сигналом, не могу решить проблему установки cookie на весь сайт. Чтобы если выключил колокольчик, то он выключался не только в разделе системы, но вообще во всей системе.

код такой:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.notification-icon').click(function(){
                $(this).next('.notification-block').slideToggle();
                $(this).toggleClass('n-active');                    

                if ($(this).hasClass('n-active')) $(this).find('span').html('&#x25B2;')
                    else $(this).find('span').html('&#x25BC;')
                });
            if (getCookie('soundjob')) {soudcont = getCookie('soundjob'); $('.control-sound').addClass(soudcont); } else { $('.control-sound').addClass('on'); cetcooke('on'); }

            $('.control-sound').click(function(){ if($(this).hasClass("on")) { $(this).removeClass('on').addClass('off'); cetcooke('off'); } else { $(this).removeClass('off').addClass('on'); cetcooke('on'); } });
        });
        function soundClick() {
            if (getCookie('soundjob') == 'on') {
              var audio = new Audio(); // Создаём новый элемент Audio
              audio.src = '/js/n3.mp3'; // Указываем путь к аудио файлу
              audio.autoplay = true; // Автоматически запускаем
            }
        }
        function notification(){

            $.ajax({
                // прочие параметры
                url: "/ajax_notification.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(json){

                    if (json[0]) {

                        $(".notification-content").html(json[0]);
                        soundClick();  
                        $(".notification-icon").addClass('bell');

                    } else {
                        $(".notification-content").html('<div class="none-notification">У вас нет новых оповещений! </div>');
                        $(".notification-icon").removeClass('bell');
                    }
                    if (json[1] > 0) {
                        $(".notification-count").html(json[1]);
                        $(".notification-count").addClass('red-count');
                    } else {
                        $(".notification-count").html('');
                        $(".notification-count").removeClass('red-count');
                    }
                }
            });

        }
        // закись в куку

        function getCookie(name) 
        {
            var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
                "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
            ));
            return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : false;
        }

        function cetcooke(status) {
            var date = new Date;
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 15); // время жизни куки
            document.cookie = "soundjob="+ status +";expires="+date.toUTCString()+"; path='*'"; // ставим куку 
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){ notification(); setInterval('notification()',20000); });
```

Answer (score 1):

Кука для всех страниц сайта пишется как **path=/**

```
document.cookie = "name=; path=/; expires=" + date.toUTCString();
```

Comment: так раньше стояло, но почему-то все равно не устанавливалась =/

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть в этой строчке

```
if (getCookie('soundjob')) {
```

Исправленная версия

```
if (getCookie('soundjob') != '') {
```

Рекомендую использовать универсальные функции для работы с cookie, передавая настройки через параметры:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
     var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
} 

function getCookie(cname) {
     var name = cname + "=";
     var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
     for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
         var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
         if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
     }
     return "";
}
```

Comment: наверное это считается отличным ответом, но чуть-чуть бы пояснений с вашей стороны не помешало.